# How do you add a custom CKEditor YAML file for each website in TYPO3?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, tsconfig, typo3-extensions

All the documentation says you need to have a custom extension to use a different preset. 
It would be a lot more user friendly if I could set the YAML path directly in TS Config on each root page.

Is there any way to set the path to a custom YAML in the Page TS Config instead of in the extension?

What I want:

**TS Config changes for each page:**

```
RTE.default.presetpath = 'fileadmin/templates/my_site/rte.yaml'
```

**Extention stays the same ext_localconf.php:**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = RTE.default.presetpath
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, follow the step below to configure the CKEditor.

- Set default preset from below configuration:

  ```
  RTE.default.preset = default
  RTE.default.preset = full
  RTE.default.preset = minimal
  ```
- Set CKEditor for default element

  ```
  RTE.tt_content.types.textmedia.bodytext.preset = default
  ```
- You can set for a custom extension with

  ```
  RTE.config.tx_news_domain_model_news.bodytext.preset = default
  ```
- Override configuration in ext_localconf.php

  ```
   if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=='111.111.111.111'){
       $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']
               ['RTE']
               ['Presets']
               ['Custom_presets'] = 'EXT:your_extension/Configuration/PageTSconfig/TceForm/Default.yaml';
   }
  ```

  That's it! you can find out more from the cool blogs here:

https://www.nitsan.in/blog/simple-steps-to-configure-ckeditor-typo3/

https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I want to set a different yaml for each website on the same installation, without having to continually update a custom extension to add presets. Is there no way to set the yaml path outside of an extension?

Comment: I am not sure, but what if you add a IP or domain condition in ext_localconf.php? Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to put the configuration in an extension.

But, TYPO3 is very flexible. You can configure it in various ways. If you use an extension (e.g. a [sitepackage](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/)) you can have all the configuration in one place, put it under version control, easily deploy it etc. This is in contrast to various configuration files in your system (e.g. in fileadmin) which is not very good practice.

If you have several sites which require different configuration in one TYPO3 installation, you can do:

1. [Define a preset](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-create-my-own-preset) for each site. You can do this in your extension as described in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/QuickStart.html) or put this in typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php:

   ```
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['site1'] = 'typo3conf/rte_site1.yaml';
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['site2'] = 'typo3conf/rte_site2.yaml';
   ```

As you can see, the path does not have to be in an extension.

2. In the Page TSconfig of your site, [select the preset](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-use-a-different-preset):

   ```
   RTE.default.preset = site1
   ```
3. Create the files rte_site1.yaml and rte_site2.yaml. You can use one of the existing configuration files as basis: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/master/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE

See also [How do I create my own preset](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-create-my-own-preset).

Comment: I don't normally make site packages but I might have to start doing it that way as you suggest.